# AngularJS - compile a directive instance on the fly

Tags: angularjs

Is is possible to generate a directive on the fly from say a controller function?

I have this sort of thing at present (I know it wont work):

```
self.untInfoWindowContent = function(untID) {

    var eventData = LastReportedEventStore.lastReportedEvents[untID];
    var element = $compile('<last-reported-event event-data="eventData"></last-reported-event>')(eventData);
    return element.html();
};
```

The eventData is coming from a keyed object variable in my LastReportedEventStore service and so I was hoping I could use it for the scope binding in the directive.

In my Jasmine test for the directive I have this kind of thing going on to compile a new instance of my directive for testing purposes:

```
var scope = rootScope.$new();

scope.eventData = {
    UntID: 12345,
    UnitName: 'Lightning McQueen',
    Location: 'M4, London, heading NE at 35mph.',
    EventDTDisplay: '18:15:05',
    InJourney: true,
    UrrID: 1

};

var element = compile('<last-reported-event event-data="eventData"></last-reported-event>')(scope);
scope.$digest();
```

So I am wanting to do the same thing from my controller function, can someone please advise?

Thanks

Comment: you should compile with scope in your `untInfoWindowContent ` function

Comment: Do you mind sharing an example please?

Comment: basically here you this `var element = $compile('<last-reported-event event-data="eventData"></last-reported-event>')(eventData);` code should compile using scope like `$compile('<last-reported-event event-data="eventData"></last-reported-event>')(scope);`

Comment: @mindparse, you should NEVER deal with DOM in controllers. (until you are confident to challenge me on that assertion). So, why don't you explain what you are *actually* trying to achieve. More specifically to your issue, your `untInfoWindowContent` is returning a text (produced by `.html`) - the fact that you compiled the directive is not reflected in the returning HTML. Not to mentioned that you are linking not against a scope (unlike in your test case, which is correct)

Comment: Sure ok, I was just experimenting and I understand your comments. My app has a list of of my last-reported-event directives (using ng-repeat) displayed alongside a map and so I just wanted to be able to select an item and then use that content generated from the directive as the content for use in an infowindow for an associated marker on the map. I would like it so that when data changes on the scope for the selected directive, the infowindow content also changes (real time location data updates).